# MySql How to show specific row on top and then remaining rows beneath it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have these records in database:

```
1. As & When Required
2. Daily
3. Bi-Weekly
4. Weekly
5. Fortnightly
6. Monthly
7. Quarterly
8. Bi-Annually
9. Annually
10. One-off
11. N/A
```

in table `TBL_SUB_FRQ`

I want to show `N/A` on top when I run select query, like this:

```
1. N/A
2. As & When Required
3. Daily
4. Bi-Weekly
5. Weekly
6. Fortnightly
7. Monthly
8. Quarterly
9. Bi-Annually
10. Annually
11. One-off
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT frequency
FROM TBL_SUB_FRQ
ORDER BY frequency = 'N/A' DESC
```

where `frequency` should be replaced with the name of the column containing that data. When a condition is true, the value is `1`; when it's false the value is `0`. So ordering by the condition allows you to put the rows that match the condition first or last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE..WHEN` expression within the `ORDER BY` Clause :

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBL_SUB_FRQ
 ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN frequency = 'N/A' THEN 
          0
       ELSE
          1
       END
```